# How to make a vlookup-equivalent with lists into dataframe columun in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd
dfX = pd.DataFrame()
dfX['Col1']=[['a','b'],['c','d']]
dfX['Col2']=['a','d']
dfX

    Col1   Col2
0   [a,b]   a
1   [c,d]   d
```

I would like to get the value in Col2 in the line which contains the list ['a','b'] in column Col1. I especially tried the following but it did not work :

```
dfX[dfX['Col1'] == ['a','b']]['Col2']
```

How can I do ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add your expected output?

Comment: Knowing  [a,b] (col1) I would like to get a (col2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as far as I understand you want 'Col1' to be exactly ['a','b'].

This is what I would do:

```
import pandas as pd
dfX = pd.DataFrame()
dfX['Col1']=[['a','b'],['c','d']]
dfX['Col2']=['a','d']

#find every row where 'Col1' is equal to ['a','b']
mask = dfX.apply(lambda x: ['a','b'] == x.Col1,axis=1)

#apply it to your dataframe
print(dfX[mask]['Col2'])
```

output:

```
0    a
Name: Col2, dtype: object
```

Comment: @Ewdlam you are welcome! Let me know if I can help you any further with this!